# Are non-standard models always not well-founded?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Are non-standard models of ZF set theory by definition always not well-founded? And it seems it is, because it must be.

But then, Wikipedia says that when there is a set that is a standard model of ZF, there exists smallest set $L_k$ that is standard model. So, this seems to confuse me a lot.

Comment: User @Mikhail, please see the intended scope of tags before you apply them. The tag [tag:nonstandard-models] is meant for models of arithmetic. It is a worthy point to consider expanding this to models of set theory as well, but you should bring this up on [meta] before you decide to take one-sided actions.

Answer (score 7):

By a *standard model* of ZF we mean a model $( M , E )$ of ZF where the relation $E$ is *real membership* on $M$, *i.e.*, $x \mathrel{E} y \; \Leftrightarrow \; x \in y$.  The relation $E$ is usually denoted either simply by $\in$, or by $\in_M$ to emphasise that we've restricted the domain.

Given any standard model $( M , \in_M )$ of ZF we can construct an isomorphic non-standard model $( M^* , E^* )$ quite easily by taking $M^* = \{ \{ x \} : x \in M \}$, and defining $\{ x \} \mathrel{E^*} \{ y \} \; \Leftrightarrow \; x \in y$.  This model will be well-founded.

Comment: Of course, by the Mostowski collapse lemma, if we have any model that is well-founded and extensional, that model is isomorphic to a model that is "standard" in the sense given here - and the collapse lemma also produces a transitive model, which is a stronger condition. So it would not cause any real difference to define a standard model to be one that, when viewed from the outside, has a well-founded membership relation (extensionality will follow automatically from the model satisfying ZF).

Comment: @Carl: I agree that "_nice_" models of ZF are for all intents and purposes standard, but the literature does not seem to use _standard_ in this wider sense.

Comment: !Arthur: my experience with the set theory literature is that "transitive model" is more common than "standard model" (although I am not a set theorist, so my experience is limited). Do Jech or Kunen define the term "standard model" in their texts?

Comment: @CarlMummert No, neither book uses the term. Curious now about a printed reference. Anyway, *standard* means that the ordinals are standard, meaning isomorphic to an initial segment of the true ordinals. This is equivalent to saying that the model is well-founded. (In particular, Arthur's example $(M^*,E^*)$ is standard. It is also standard practice to replace well-founded parts by their transitive collapses, so it is common to abuse language and just say that a model is standard if its membership relation is true membership.)

Comment: @Carl: As Andres mentions neither Kunen or Jech use the term.  I've looked in a few other places and the only text I have been able to find it is in Just and Weese's _Discovering Modern Set Theory_ (which is also the first set-theory text I ever studied).  Google provided very few references to the definition I have used.  The only positive seems to be that [Wikipedia's _Inner Model_ article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_model) uses this definition, which is where the OP's question originated.

Answer (score 7):

There are several different senses in which a set model of ZF set theory could be "standard". I have marked this answer as community wiki, so please feel free to add any other definitions that you think of.

1. The model could have an $\omega$ that is isomorphic to the standard $\omega$. These models are called $\omega$-*models*.
2. The membership relation of the model could be well founded when viewed from the outside. These models are called *well founded models*.
3. The model could use the standard membership relation $\in$ rather than some other membership relation. These models are sometimes called *standard models*.
4. The model could be a transitive set, and use the standard membership relation $\in$. A transitive set is a set $A$ such that, for all $B \in A$, every member of $B$ is also a member of $A$. These models are called *transitive models*.

For any given model, (4) implies (3) implies (2) implies (1), and none of the converse implications hold in general.

The [Mostowski collapse lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostowski_collapse_lemma) shows that every model of ZF satisfying (2) is isomorphic to a model satisfying (4).